# nodejs - Passing data (module) to Jade from file

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, server-side-rendering

I'm developing a small battle simulator similar to Pokémon Showdown. I'm using express and pug (jade) for rendering html. It is not about Pokémon, but if you know the website you may get a better reference. I have been inspecting its [public github repo](https://github.com/smogon/pokemon-showdown) but I get lost about how they do things.

I have a module with data similar as follows:

```js
// public/data.js
const Units = {
    "Swordsman": { ... }, // data of the Swordsman unit
    "Healer": { ... }, // data of the Healer unit
    ... // ~ 500 additional entries
};
export { Units as default };
```

On the client-side I am perfectly able to import it using `import Units from './data.js'`. However, on the teambuilder I want to display all the available units through a pug/jade template:

```
- for (unit in Units)
    li= unit.name
```

How can I pass the data to the template? I tried on the router:

```js
import Units from './data.js';
router.get('/batallions', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('batallions', {
    title: 'Batallions',
    Units: Units
  });
});
```

Tried both `import ... from ...` and `require()`, but it gave me errors:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import Units from './data.js';
                                                                     ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

and:

```
export { Units as default };
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

It works perfectly when I import it on the client-side, but can not pass it to the template to display it. Is there a way of doing this? I could instead use a database, but I need the client to load the Units data too. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the problem may be that `export { Unit as default }` works for client-side, whereas server-side expects `module.exports`. So the solutions seems to be having duplicated data for client- and server-. I hope anyone has a better approach, otherwise I will just have to move to a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing your `export` statement in `data.js` as:

```
module.exports = Units
```

And then use `require()` on the router as:

```
const Units = require('./data.js')
```

Comment: But then I can't use the `import Units from './data.js'` on the client, right? Although I could just send the Units data through the router. Thanks! I will mark you as the accepted answer if there are no more answers in a while ^^

Comment: Yes, it may be best to just send it through the router where you need it.